# increasing dimensions of input for NN

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I have a NN I built that requires 4 dimensions of input. I'm now just using it for single instance predictions, but I can't figure out how to increase the number of dimensions to 4. When I initially trained and tested the model, the input would look like:

```
(16238, 40, 40, 1)
```

Where the first dimension was the number of rows, the second and third were the matrix dimensions, and then the fourth was the depth of the matrix.

Now, I'm just trying to test individual items using the model, but can't find a way to increase the dimensions. Its like:

```
>>> array = [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

>>> array.shape
(3, 3)
```

So I'd like to change the array shape to something like:

```
(1, 3, 3, 1)
```

I tried:

```
array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=-1)
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `array.reshape((1, 3, 3, 1))` is what you're looking for?

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: array = np.asarray([[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])

In [3]: array.shape
Out[3]: (3, 3)

In [4]: array
Out[4]:
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])

# keep original dimensions in 2nd and 3rd dimension
In [5]: reshaped = array.reshape((1, *array.shape, 1))

In [6]: reshaped.shape
Out[6]: (1, 3, 3, 1)

In [7]: reshaped
Out[7]:
array([[[[1],
         [1],
         [1]],

        [[1],
         [2],
         [3]],

        [[1],
         [2],
         [3]]]])
```

Comment: Do you think I could hire you for some freelance work? I need a model deployed and I have no familiarity with flask, would just like someone to show me how its done.